# Nested Map Structure Create Empty Map

Tags: c++, dictionary, data-structures, initialization

I'm don't get this to work. I want to initialize the following structure for later use.

```
map<pair<string,string>, map<string,vector<fs::path>>> filelist;
```

Thats means I provide the string pair for the first map. (e.g., "id1","id2") with an empty second map that I can fill in later. So I want to do something like this:

```
filelist.insert(
     pair<pair<string,string>, pair<string,vector<fs::path>>>
     (make_pair("id1","id2), **empty map??**));
```

Obviously when when I stick to the vector instead of the nested map I can do this:

```
filelist.insert(pair<pair<string, string>, vector<vector<fs::path>>>
     (make_pair("id1","id2"),{}) );
```

But how can I initialize an empty map? Or is there an alternative data structure? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to initialize the following structure for later use.
>   `map<pair<string,string>, map<string,vector<fs::path>>> filelist;`

You can use `operator[]` to assign it.
Some thing like follows.

```
filelist[ std::make_pair("string1", "string2") ]   = value();
```

where, `using value =  std::map< std::string, std::vector<int>>;`

See live action: https://www.ideone.com/lxQir7

> is there an alternative data structure?

A suggestion to reduce the complexity of your chosen data-structure is possible, only when you explain your problem and data manipulation requirements more in detail.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using key = std::pair< std::string, std::string>;
using value =  std::map< std::string, std::vector<int>>;

int main ()
{
   std::map< key , value > filelist;

   value vMap;
   vMap["string"] = {1,2,3,4};

   filelist[ std::make_pair("string1", "string2") ]   = vMap;

   // to print or access 
   for(auto& key_itr: filelist)
   {
      std::cout<< "KEY: " << key_itr.first.first << " " << key_itr.first.second << "\t VALUE: ";

      for(auto& val_itr: key_itr.second)
      {
         std::cout << val_itr.first << " ";

         for(const auto& vec: val_itr.second)   std::cout << vec << " ";
      }
      std::cout << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can initialize an empty map, simply by its default constructor.
It is always a better idea to name your newly introduced data types.
After all, it's a relatively complex data structure. Why don't you simplify your problem?

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <filesystem>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::filesystem;

using string_to_vector_of_path_map = map<string, vector<path>>;
using pair_of_strings = pair<string, string>;
using my_map = map<pair_of_strings, string_to_vector_of_path_map>;

my_map filelist;

int main()
{
    filelist.insert(make_pair(make_pair("id1", "id2"), string_to_vector_of_path_map()));
    return 0;
}
```